# How to set first argument label in objective c to use in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, parameters, arguments, label

I thought to use first argument label of objective function in swift, it can be done by adding preposition to function name.

```
- (void) makeRoundedWithCornerRadius: (CGFloat) cornerRadius;
```

I can use it in swift project like this (It is what I expected)

```
myView.makeRounded(withCornerRadius: 16)
```

And I made another function like this

```
- (void) makeBorderWithColor: (UIColor*) color width: (CGFloat) width;
```

However when I'm about to use it in swift, first argument label does not show the way I expected.
What I expected was

```
myView.makeBorder(withColor: .red, width: 10)
```

But it showed like..

```
myView.makeBorder(with: .red, width: 10)
```

It eliminates color label.
I am very confused and even  can't guess the rule.

What is the rule that convert Objective-C function name to Swift's first argument label? And is it other way to make first argument label that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method renaming – `NS_SWIFT_NAME` keyword:

```
- (void) makeRoundedWithCornerRadius: (CGFloat) cornerRadius width: (CGFloat) width NS_SWIFT_NAME(makeBorder(withColor:width:));
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objective-c_and_c_code_customization/renaming_objective-c_apis_for_swift